# How to fail .NET 4.5 build with Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, nuget

I am attempting to use `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers` in a legacy .NET 4.5 app that cannot be upgraded for *reasons*.

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/overview) you can install the `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers` NuGet package and use the Analysers in 'older' .net versions. How old, I am not sure.

> If you don't want to move to the .NET 5+ SDK, have a non-SDK-style
> .NET Framework project, or prefer a NuGet package-based model, the
> analyzers are also available in the
> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers NuGet package.

The Errors do show in the Visual Studio Error List under "Build + IntelliSense" but do not show under the regular "Build" so subsequently the build does not fail even if there are errors configured in the .editorconfig

I imagine that the Visual Studio IntelliSense is using the .NET 5 SDK to show the errors and then the actual build is using .NET 4.5 so is unaware of the analysis rules? But then what is the NuGet package supposed to be doing?

Is this just not supported in such an old .NET Framework version? That quote from the documentation suggests that some older frameworks should be able to use it.

I have a blank, file new project .NET 4.5 Console app with `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers` installed and a simple .editorconfig with a sample rule

```
dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0010.severity = error
```

If so, what are alternatives? [StyleCop "Classic"](https://github.com/StyleCop/StyleCop)?

Answer (score 1):

As I know old code analysis uses `ruleset` file, not `.editorconfig`. I found also [documentation about it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/using-rule-sets-to-group-code-analysis-rules?view=vs-2019).
I use code analysis in .NET Framework projects like this:

- right-click on the project and go to `Properties`,
- go to `Code Analysis` tab,
- in active rules there is by default `Microsoft Managed Recommended Rules` - click on `Configure` button,
- search for `IDE0010` and select `error` and save ruleset,
- ensure that now in `Code Analysis` tab you have your file selected in active rules option.

Comment: Hi Lukasz. Thanks for your answer. Are you using VS 2019? I cannot get this to fail the build either. I am on v16.10.3

Comment: I am also very curious as to what the 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers' NuGet package is supposed to be doing?

Comment: I have VS 16.9.5 and I see this error only in IntelliSense and in errors panel, but it doesn't trigger build failure. Still, something is missing, I installed NuGet Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers. I will look at it again, I had a similar issue in the past too :(

Comment: @SamLeach another update - I found https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/6195, and my understanding is that IDE is not a compiler rule, so it will not show during the build process.

Comment: I also agree with @LukaszSzczygielek . The IDE related rule is not used for compiler rule, and it is designed like this. `StyleCop` may be the alternatives, or you can suggest this feature on [Microsoft Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=8&entry=suggestion).